# react-native-vlc echo / reverbing audio bug

Tags: android, react-native, libvlc

I have forked and fixed an old react-native package that allows you to use the VLC media player but the audio has what can only be described as an echo or reverb

I have tried using different options for vlc in the PlayerActivity.java file and i am currently using

```
options.add("--file-caching=150");
options.add("-vv");
options.add(":network-caching=150");
options.add(":clock-jitter=0");
options.add(":clock-syncro=0");
```

you can install the package from my github at this link i currently use it on react-native 0.60.5

https://github.com/Rob2k9/react-native-vlc-player

i am hopping to get the video and audio to play like expected and normal with no echo / reverb

I am no java expert and have only been using react-native a couple of months so this is all new on me and i need a little help

Comment: libvlc version? Try a 3+ if it's not already

Comment: Currently using : de.mrmaffen:libvlc-android:2.1.12

Comment: try reading the same media with VLC Android. If it works, you probably need to update your libvlc (do it either way)

Comment: i updated to libvlc 3.* and same issue still exists i have done some digging and i am not sure if it is actually an audio issue 

if i disable the video the audio plays fine but with the video re enabled echos again

Comment: Try with VLC Android app

Comment: vlc android app works fine so i know its something todo with the react-native implamentation i have a feeling its an issue todo with the way the player is loaded due to the fact audio plays fine with no video but as soon as there is video as well its echoing / reverbing

Comment: remove all libvlc options and try. Check which libvlc options vlc-android uses. Compare logs.